# Moderator action popup doesn't support Markdown, but contains item with it

Tags: bug, markdown, moderator-tools, convert-to-edit

Moderator action popup has an option "convert to edit":

> [image]

<sup>* text autotranslated to English</sup>

[Original text](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/7688) here is:

> `Answers should be converted to an edit of the question when they represent additional/supporting information **by the asker**. The body of the answer is appended to the question.`

As you can notice this text contains Markdown - double asterisk. But rendering here doesn't support it.

At the same time it works in user level mod menu:

> [image]